# JavaScript: getting a string with '\ to display

Tags: javascript, string, include, escaping, backslash

I'm working on a project in which I need to be able to display the following string in a sentence in its entirety.

```
let string = "\' testing \'";
```

Basically, I'm trying to account for all possible cases. Now, how do I go about escaping the \ and getting the entire string to display?

I've tried this:

```
if (string.includes("\\")) {
                newString = string.replace(/\\/g, "&bsol;");
}
```

but then I get this:

```
newString = "'testing'"
```

The backslashes are gone! Any insight as to why this might not be working?

Comment: to "hard code" a \ in a string, use \\ - because as written the string actually is `' testing '` because escaping `'` has no effect, just the \ is dropped ... i.e `let string = "\\' testing \\'";`

Comment: If you want to obtain `\' testing \'` just create a string like this `\\\' testing \\\'`. The result is just a normal comportement

Comment: The problem here isn't the string. The string is provided already. I need to modify the function itself.